# How do I use one method for multiple DTO?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity, dto

I have an Address entity as follows:

```
public class Address
{
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
    public string? Contact { get; set; }
    public string? Street1 { get; set; }
    public string? Street2 { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? Zip { get; set; }
}
```

According to the best practices, I use different DTOs for different parts of app according to the users' needs. Suppose that I have two DTOs from the Address entity as follows:

```
public class AddressDto1
    {
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? Country { get; set; }
        public string? Contact { get; set; }
        public string? Street1 { get; set; }
        public string? Street2 { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? Zip { get; set; }
    } 
public class AddressDto2
    { 
        [Requierd]
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        [Requierd]
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? Zip { get; set; }
    }
```

User1 can see and create the Address by AddressDto1 field, and User2 can see and create the Address by AddressDto2 field.
I have a method in the service that inherit from an interface and I use `AutoMapper` to map the DTO to Entity.

```
public interface IAddressService
{
    public Task<AddressDto1> CreateAddressAsync(AddressDto1 AddressDto1);
}

public class AddressService:IAddressService
{
    public Task<AddressDto1> CreateAddressAsync(AddressDto1 addressDto1)
    {
        var newAddress = _mapper.Map<Address>(addressDto1);
        var addedAddress = await _dbContext.Addresses.AddAsync(newAddress);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<AddressDto1>(addedAddress.Entity);
    }
}
```

And it's mapping profile:

```
public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AddressDto1, Address>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<AddressDto2, Address>().ReverseMap();
    }
```

I'd like to use `CreateAddressAsync` for any `AddressDto`s.
What should be the best way to implement `CreateAddressAsync` method so that the `AddressDto2` can be added to the bank with the same method?

Comment: `public Task<AddressDto> CreateAddressAsync(AddressDto AddressDto);` - I see no need for AdressDto1/AdressDto2. With JsonSettings which skips null properties you will see no difference in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make you method generic so that you can call the service for both models

```cs
public async Task<T> CreateAddressAsync<T>(T addressDto1)
    {
        var newAddress = _mapper.Map<T, Address>(T);
        var addedAddress = await _dbContext.Addresses.AddAsync(newAddress);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<Address, T>(addedAddress.Entity);
    }

//calling service
var address1= await _addressService.CreateAddressAsync<AddressDto>(model);
```

You can have more control over input parameters by having a base model for address dto after you can add this `where T: baseAddress`

Also you can make data layer generic by `_dbContext.Set<TEntity>`.